# Importing components in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm coming over to Vue from React and am trying to figure out how to use imported components. I mean, components which were created and published on NPM by someone else.

Specifically, I'm looking at this: http://vuejs.creative-tim.com/vue-paper-dashboard

I'd like to use its components inside my project, but keep the overall project structure-user management and authentication, etc.

Short of copy-pasting components, is there a good way to do this with Vue? With React, I would just do an import and pass the relevant props to each component.

Comment: You may use the same import sintaxis as you use in React. `import Vue from 'vue'` for example

Comment: What have you tried? If you're using Webpack, you just `import` the component, assign it to the [`components` property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Module-Systems) and use the snake-cased version in your template